# Copy first row in grid

Tags: javascript, asp.net

just want to ask if it is possible to copy the first value of the row in grid?
For example. I have two column. A and B value are. If I put any value in column B at the first row. It should be fill all the remaining row.

```
**Serial**   **CartNum**   Output **CartNum**
    1             1                    1
    2                                  1
    3                                  1
    4                                  1
```

Is this possible? I'm using ASP.NET(VB), javascript for this I think?

Here's my grid code.

```
<div class="Scrolls">
  <asp:DataGrid runat="server" ID="dgSerial" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="false" ShowHeader="false" GridLines="None" DataKeyField="BaseLineNum" AlternatingItemStyle-CssClass="AlternateGrid">
    <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateColumn>
        <ItemTemplate>
          <table border="0" style="border-bottom: 1px dotted; border-color: #FF0000">
            <tr>
              <td style="width: 20px;">
                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkSelect"></asp:CheckBox>
              </td>
              <td style="width: 120px;">
                <asp:TextBox Width="120" ID="SerialNum" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SerialNum")%>' />
              </td>
              <td style="width: 120px;">
                <asp:TextBox Width="120" ID="CartNum" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CartNum")%>' />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateColumn>
    </Columns>
  </asp:DataGrid>
</div>
```

Hope to hear positive response.

Comment: Of course that is possible to copy a value in other place. But I don't get your point here... can you try to explain yourself a little better?

Comment: what kind of gird it is? are you using HTML table?

Comment: I think the point is , if he type `1` in row1 , columnB , he want to copy this value to remaining rows of columnB . (Client Side) !

Comment: Zey was correct. That's my point experts. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Mannish, I'm using ASP grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must edit your second row template as above:

```
<asp:TextBox Width="120" ID="CartNum" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CartNum")%>'
  onchange="javascript: copy();" CssClass="row2"/>
```

And then add the Javascript magic:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function copy() {
    var cells = document.getElementsByClassName("row2");
    for(var i = 1; i < cells.length; i++)
      cells[i].value = cells[0].value;
  }
</script>
```

I'm not able to test this right now, so I'm not sure that it will work fine but I'm sure it will with a few modifications.

Note that the javascript code is always taking the value from the first cell of the column (cells[0]), due in your question that was what you were asking for.

Comment: Hi adripanico, I'm having an error "0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementsByClassName'"

Comment: Are you sure you are writing `getElementsByClassName` and not `getElementByClassName`?

Comment: you should use onkeyup event. for this.

Comment: onchange is also valid

Comment: Hi @adripanico, yes I'm sure that I used getElementsByClassName. Based from your code. Sorry for late response.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will help you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function copy(){
    var inputCount = document.getElementById('tableId').getElementsByTagName('input').length;
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    for(i=1;i<=inputCount;i++){
    document.getElementById('name_'+i).value = name;
    }
}
</script>
<table id="tableId">
<tr>
<td>
    <input type="text" id="name" onkeyup="copy();" name="name" />
    <input type="text" id="name_1" name="name_1" />
    <input type="text" id="name_2" name="name_2" />
    <input type="text" id="name_3" name="name_3" />
    <input type="text" id="name_4" name="name_4" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That's a good approach but due you have several rows, you will need to use a different way to get the elements, for example with getElementByClass. You also will need to use a `foreach` loop.

Comment: Thanks for this. But how can I apply this in my grid?